# How to use Jenkins P4 plugin publish for declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

```
stage('Publish Assets')
{ 
     when{ 
      expression { //some condition } 
     } 
     steps{ 
         p4publish(
             credential: 'abcd', 
             publish: [$class: 'SubmitImpl', delete: false, description: 'Submitted by Jenkins. Build: ${BUILD_TAG}', onlyOnSuccess: true, purge: '', reopen: false], 
             workspace: [$class: 'ManualWorkspaceImpl', charset: 'none', name: 'jenkins-abcd-publish', pinHost: false, spec: [allwrite: true, backup: false, clobber: false, compress: false, line: 'LOCAL', locked: false, modtime: false, rmdir: false, serverID: '', streamName: '//abcd/efg', type: 'WRITABLE', view: '']]) 
     } 
}
```

I tried a couple of things and placing it under script block as well but no luck. Is it not suppose to work with declarative pipelines or am I missing something? It would be nice if I could get some help on this

Answer (score 1):

Found this guide in the P4 plugin repo that might help. They seem to suggest using the snippet generator to help with getting the syntax correct.  The examples they show are written with the imperative syntax, but I don't see why it wouldn't work for declarative.

```
node {
  stage('Sync') {
    // sync files from //streams/st1-main/...
    p4sync(charset: 'none',
      credential: 'phooey1666', 
      populate: [$class: 'AutoCleanImpl', 
        delete: true, 
        modtime: false, 
        pin: '',
        quiet: true,
        replace: true],
      stream: '//streams/st1-main')
  }
}
```

p4 publish https://github.com/jenkinsci/p4-plugin/blob/master/WORKFLOW.md#using-standard-freestyle-jobs-steps

```
p4publish(credential: 'phooey1666', 
  publish: [$class: 'SubmitImpl', 
    delete: false, 
    description: 'Submitted by Jenkins. Build: ${BUILD_TAG}', 
    onlyOnSuccess: false, 
    purge: '', 
    reopen: false], 
  workspace: [$class: 'StreamWorkspaceImpl', 
    charset: 'none', 
    format: 'jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}-publish', 
    pinHost: false, 
    streamName: '//streams/st2-rel1'])
```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/p4-plugin/blob/master/WORKFLOW.md

Comment: also if you could post the error message you're getting in your original question that would help too :)

Comment: There is no error . So in the logs all is see is p4publish and nothing more on it. I did use the syntax generator and that's how I created the above stage. The same syntax works for scripted pipeline . The only difference in declarative and scripted is I wrapped it in 'steps' and added an expressION condition. P4publish in the log does show that nothing is wrong with my jenkinsfile. Below is the log for that stage
This is the log for that stage:
`[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Publish Assets)
[Pipeline] p4publish
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage`

Comment: that is really wierd, and yea that log is not helpful. How about the jenkins server log, is there any useful info there?